# Parsing HTML content

Tags: html, ios, parsing, xpath, tfhpple

I am parsing the link http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/NDTV-Tech/~3/YNW1kE-FDv0/story01.htm to get the contents from 'HeadContent_FullstoryCtrl_fulldetails' HTML tag. I am using TFHpple and pointing xpath parser to the HTML element using //*[@id='HeadContent_FullstoryCtrl_fulldetails'].

The response of this is in an NSArray which has the output as in below sample. I need to get only 'nodeContent' data so that i can get the news details alone.

```
<__NSArrayM 0x16d73950>(
{
    nodeAttributeArray =     (
                {
            attributeName = id;
            nodeContent = "HeadContent_FullstoryCtrl_fulldetails";
        },
                {
            attributeName = class;
            nodeContent = description;
        }
    );
    nodeChildArray =     (
                {
            nodeChildArray =             (
                                {
                    nodeContent = "The Lumia 1520 has two big things working against it, neither of \nwhich is a deal-breaker on its own, but when combined, make it a very \ninteresting product to review. First, it's a Windows Phone. While the \nplatform certainly does have its fans, there's no denying that it isn't \nas versatile as iOS and Android yet. As a person buying this phone, you \nwill have to put up with a number of limitations and frustrations \nbecause of its software. Second, it's huge. So-called \"phablets\" are big\n business, but not everybody wants a phone that can't fit in a pocket \nand be held in one hand. With that said, it's time to examine this phone\n on its own merits and see whether Nokia has managed to distinguish \nitself with a winner.";
                    nodeName = text;
                }
            );
            nodeName = p;
            raw = "<p>The Lumia 1520 has two big things working against it, neither of \nwhich is a deal-breaker on its own, but when combined, make it a very \ninteresting product to review. First, it's a Windows Phone. While the \nplatform certainly does have its fans, there's no denying that it isn't \nas versatile as iOS and Android yet. As a person buying this phone, you \nwill have to put up with a number of limitations and frustrations \nbecause of its software. Second, it's huge. So-called \"phablets\" are big\n business, but not everybody wants a phone that can't fit in a pocket \nand be held in one hand. With that said, it's time to examine this phone\n on its own merits and see whether Nokia has managed to distinguish \nitself with a winner.</p>";
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

NSXMLParser will handle this for you : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Earlier i tried parsing using NSXML but was unable to get the contents of a specific HTML tag. I used 'zootreeves / Objective-C-HMTL-Parser' for parsing. Thanks.

Comment: It is possible using NSXML - you just need to read the child nodes.

Comment: Could you please share an example or link which explains the steps. I want to parse the link <http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/NDTV-Tech/~3/YNW1kE-FDv0/story01.htm> and get contents of 'HeadContent_FullstoryCtrl_fulldetails'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to read the specific details of an HTML tag with the help of 'zootreeves / Objective-C-HMTL-Parser' https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser.

Just wanted to post the answer as it might help others!.